# How to check internet connection with c?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I'm making an application based on networking. The first thing it should do is check if the user has an internet connection.For this I tried using functions given in header  like (InternetCheckConnection & ConnectionStat) but whenever I try to compile I get errors similar to this one => reference to `InternetCheckConnectionA@12' so I tried to change compiler (from devc++ to Code::Blocks) but the same problem...

Is there another way to check for internet connection with c?

Comment: [ping.c](http://www.google.com)

Comment: "How to check internet connection with C?" - You look at the cable and C if it's plugged in.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778404/programmatically-check-whether-my-machine-has-internet-access-or-not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778404/programmatically-check-whether-my-machine-has-internet-access-or-not)

Comment: "How to check internet connection with C" and question is marked with C++? **C++ is not C!!!**

Comment: Why not just try to connect to whatever you want to get to on the internet and then handle it if you can't get there?

Comment: What platform do you need to do it on?  Windows? Linux? OSX? iOS? Android NDK?

Comment: Also where does inetnetCheckConnection come from?  If you have unresolved externals you probably forgot to link a library into your executable.

Answer (score 0):

InetnetCheckConnection causes linking error because you probably(certainly) didn't link Wininet.lib
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx