# C++ Check Internet Connection on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c++, networking, poco-libraries

Is there any way to check Internet Connection on Linux Ubuntu? Because  this one is only for Windows-- [programmatically check whether my machine has internet access or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778404/programmatically-check-whether-my-machine-has-internet-access-or-not)

Or Using Poco libraries.

Comment: What was wrong with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15778448/366904), given in the same question? Use the sockets library to connect to a known address.

Comment: @CodyGray How can we implement it?

Comment: Using the sockets library, like I already said. I guess this was really a "give-me-teh-codez" question.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! I found right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use route command in Linux to check

```
FILE *output;

if(!(output = popen("/sbin/route -n | grep -c '^0\\.0\\.0\\.0'","r")))
{
    return 1;
}
unsigned int i;
fscanf(output,"%u",&i);
if(i == 1)
       cerr<<"There is internet connection\n";
else if(i == 0)
       cerr<<"There is no internet connection\n";
pclose(output);
```

You can find more information about it [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/route.htm).

Comment: It will only give you the information that a default route is set. but if you can reach internet ip addresses will not be guaranteed. therefor you should open a connection to  a well known ip address in the internet like 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.8.4 (google DNS server)